# All elements are re-rendered when any @State/@Binding variable is updated in SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui, rendering, auto-update

I have a **List** view. **ForEach** element there is a *card* which is a child class. Data has been passed to the child class using **@Binding**. There is a button in the child class which updates the @Binding element. I am using a plugin named **Pages**(https://github.com/nachonavarro/Pages) to show a slideShow of images in the listView's *card*.

Problem: Every time I update a state/binding element onButtonPress, the plugin **Pages** re-renders due to which I see flickering when updation. Is there a way to prevent or solve this problem???

Questions that come to my mind:

- Is there any way to prevent the plugin from re-rendering?
- Why does the all the elements update in a View even though there is just 1 element dependent on the updated state variable?

Comment: It is expected that view is re-rendered on State/Binding change. Would you show your code?

Comment: define your data holder class separately from view struct, then define let obj in view , this will does not update your views when updating the data holder